# jquery checkbox if statement not working anymore

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, if-statement, checkbox

letterChr, numberChr, and symbolChr were originally designated as ids but had to update them recently to a class after I needed second set of buttons (which I did on both the html and javascript) and while every variation works the if statement to set the global variable to 4 doesn't and it instead defaults to 3. any help would be appreciated.

the javascript code

```js
var letterChr = $('.letters')
var numberChr = $('.numbers')
var symbolsChr = $('.characters')

function SelectorChr() {
  if (letterChr.is(':checked') && numberChr.is(':checked') && symbolsChr.is(':checked')) {
    chooser = 1
    console.log('checked')
  } else if (letterChr.is(':checked') && numberChr.is(':not(:checked)') && symbolsChr.is(':not(:checked)')) {
    chooser = 3
    console.log('checked 3')

  } else if (letterChr.is(':checked') && numberChr.is(':not(:checked)') && symbolsChr.is(':checked')) {
    chooser = 4
    console.log('checked 4')
  } else {
    chooser = 0
    alert('No checkboxes have been selected')
    return
  }
}
```

the html code

```html
<ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
  <li class="list-group-item">
    <label for="letters">Letters</label>
    <input type="checkbox" class="letters">
  </li>
  <li class="list-group-item">
    <label for="numbers">Numbers</label>
    <input type="checkbox" class="numbers">
  </li>
  <li class="list-group-item">
    <label for="characters">Characters</label>
    <input type="checkbox" class="characters">
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Where are `letterChr`, `numberChr` and `symbolsChr`? You haven't included where you get those in your code. Please [edit] your question to include all of the relevant code so we can see what's happening and be able to help.

Comment: You probably just have to change your jQuery selectors.

Comment: okay I just updated it

Comment: Changing from an id to a class will potentially get you more than one result based on how classes are normally used. Why not output letterChr, numberChr, and symbolsChr and see what those are.

Comment: first `else if` is invalid syntax. read your console (F12)

Comment: How are watching the change event on those `checkboxes` are you using click or a change function to update the `chooser` on `checkbox` selection ?

Comment: AlwaysHelping I'm using a click event on a separate button that then runs the if statement

Comment: Mister Jojo it isn't what I posted is a snippet of a large if statement

Comment: please create a Minimal, Reproducible Example ; https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: `<labels` parts can't work if there is `id` corresponding on `for` attributes

Comment: forgot to mentions there a two set of buttons but again in every variation the if statement works its only 4 that seems to be having an issue

Comment: so `letterChr`,  and others have become arrays of two elements

Comment: yeah two arrays of checkboxes with the same class

Comment: If you have changed from id to class, then I assume there must be multiple instances. Then you need to specify. Because if you just test for class selector and any of the checkboxes having that class is unchecked, the is(':checked') will return false.

Answer (score 0):

I made a simple html page to test your code, and what I find is that you shouldn't use the numberChr.is(':not(:checked)') instead you should use !numberChr.is(':checked'). see the code sample below. I think this is what you were looking for.

```
<ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
    <li class="list-group-item">
      <label for="letters">Letters</label>
      <input type="checkbox" class="letters">
    </li>
    <li class="list-group-item">
      <label for="numbers">Numbers</label>
      <input type="checkbox" class="numbers">
    </li>
    <li class="list-group-item">
      <label for="characters">Characters</label>
      <input type="checkbox" class="characters">
    </li>
  </ul>
  <script type="text/javascript">
        var letterChr = $('.letters')
        var numberChr = $('.numbers')
        var symbolsChr = $('.characters')

        function SelectorChr(){
            if (letterChr.is(':checked') && numberChr.is(':checked') && symbolsChr.is(':checked')) {
                chooser = 1
                console.log('checked')
            } else if (letterChr.is(':checked') && !numberChr.is(':checked') && !symbolsChr.is(':checked')) {
                chooser = 3
                console.log('checked 3')

            } else if (letterChr.is(':checked') && !numberChr.is(':checked') && symbolsChr.is(':checked')) {
                chooser = 4
                console.log('checked 4')
            } else {
                chooser = 0
                alert('No checkboxes have been selected')
                return
            }
        }
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

so the problem only seems to persist as long as the second button set stays and only with the specific conditions of 4. So I resolved it by adding an element remove function outside the document.ready function and called it a day.

So thank you everyone for helping me out I greatly appreciated it.